# Mixpanel is not defined for initial tracking calls

Tags: javascript, web-analytics, mixpanel

I am using asynchronously loaded mixpanel. On my homepage there are some mixpanel track calls which get fired before mixpanel js file gets loaded so those calls get mixpanel variable undefined. How to send those tracking calls?

Comment: What are you loading asynchronously and why isn't it working? The snippet at https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript sets up a small chunk of code that sets up the mixpanel variable to queue tracking calls and then loads the full Mixpanel JavaScript asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps I'm waiting when mixpanel is initialized and only then started to use it:

```
    mixpanel.init('yout app key', {
       loaded: function () {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                     //do your action here
                 }, 1);
              }
    });
```

You could broadcast some event on 'body' after init and call some track functions when event is triggered.